# Unable to save configurable product programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am try to save configurable product programmatically, But when i just hit save button in admin panel after the configurable product save the simple product only.

```
<?php

                $productId = 612; // Configurable Product Ids
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load Configurable Product
                $product->setName('90i111');
               // $product->save();
                $attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
                $position = 0;
                $attributes = array(90); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product
                $associatedProductIds = array($simple_productid); //Product Ids Of Associated Products


                foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
                    $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $productId, 'position' => $position);
                    $position++;
                    $attributeModel->setData($data)->save();
                }
                $product->setTypeId("configurable"); // Setting Product Type As Configurable
                $product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes(4);
                $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
                $product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId(4); // Setting Attribute Set Id
                $product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
                $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
                $product->save();
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add   error_reporting(1);
         ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); on your code startup

Comment: I am having a similar issue (many people are), do we have any suggestions or resolutions on this? My products do save, after something like 5 minutes of the process just sitting there as far as I can tell. they are 1 configuration with 2-6 options in the product each, most 2.